# Getting error on executing the code

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is the part of a query. If I am executing the except this I am getting the proper output.
But If i am including this query, I am getting Error :

> Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SP_CUR_LEAR, Line 294
>   No column name was specified for column 1 of 'CTE_DATE'.

Also I need to insert the data in the table #lear1 with no date gaps.

```
;WITH CTE_DATE AS ( 
  SELECT  @start_date 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT  @start_date + 1
  FROM CTE_DATE  
  WHERE @start_date  <=  @End_Date
),
CTE AS 
(
Select CTE_DATE.St_Date eff_date 
From CTE_Date
),
C (eff_date, partnumber, total_price) as
(select CTE.eff_date, PARTNUMBER, ISNULL(X.cnt,(Select Z.cnt
          From (Select AA.Totalprice cnt, Rank() Over(Order By AA.eff_date asc) RN 
                                        From #LEAR AA 
                                      Where AA.eff_date < CTE.eff_date OR AA.eff_date = CTE.eff_date
                                                                              ) Z 
                                                                        Where Z.RN = 1)) 
 from CTE 
Left Outer Join (Select eff_date, partnumber, totalprice  cnt From #lear) X ON X.eff_date = CTE.eff_date     
)

insert into #lear1 (eff_date, partnumber, totalprice)
 select eff_date, partnumber, total_price from c
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed an Alias name for the `CTE_DATE`. Adding alias name `St_Date` for `@start_date` and handle the same in the other places will solve the issue.

In case if you want to add a Day + 1, you can use `DATEADD`

```
;WITH CTE_DATE AS ( 
  SELECT @start_date AS St_Date
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATEADD(DAY, +1, St_Date) AS St_Date
  FROM CTE_DATE  
  WHERE St_Date <=  @End_Date
),
CTE AS 
(
Select CTE_DATE.St_Date eff_date 
From CTE_Date
),
C (eff_date, partnumber, total_price) as
....
....
```

Comment: @Rains Could you confirm the above answer is works? If not we can add/alter for the correct solution.

Comment: @Rains feedback plz?